# Call api using alomafier request get data inside a response but below request it get blank

Tags: swift, alamofire

I call this function I get json response from alomafier request but when I declare global variable and stored data in variable getting from  result  but print variable below response loop it get blank or nil.

I use array of Dictionary but not get solution.

```
Alamofire.request(url,method: .post).responseJSON { response in
var data1 = response.result.value ---- I get response here but not get result outside of the loop
```

**Code :**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell_view

    var domain:[[String:String]] = []


    var asyncObj:Operations = Operations()
    var url:String = asyncObj.getUrl("ticket", operation: "get_domain", filter: "")
    Alamofire.request(url,method: .post).responseJSON { response in

        var data1 = response.result.value
        //let data1 = response.data

        if(data1 != nil)
        {
            var json1 = JSON(data1!)
            GlobalVar.myvar = 10
            let count: Int? = json1.array?.count
            var departmentList = [DEPARTMENT]()
            for index in 0 ..< count! {
                var domainid = json1[index]["domain_id"]
                var domainname = json1[index]["domain_name"].stringValue
                self.numbers.append(count!)
                cell.nameLabel.text = "- "+domainname

                var url:String = asyncObj.getUrl("ticket", operation: "get_department", filter: "vis_filter=avis_domain.domain_id=\(domainid)")
                Alamofire.request(url,method: .post).responseJSON { response in

                    var data2 = response.result.value
                    var departmentList:[[String:String]] = []
                    if data2 != nil {
                        var json2 = JSON(data2!)
                        var count2: Int? = json2.array?.count
                        for index2 in 0 ..< count2!{
                            var departmentid = json2[index2]["department_id"]
                            var departmentname = json2[index2]["department_name"]
                            //departmentList.append(["departmentid": "\(departmentid)", "departmentname": "\(departmentname)"])
                            cell.addressLabel.text = "- "+"\(departmentname)";
                            var url:String = asyncObj.getUrl("ticket", operation: "get_department_status_list", filter: "vis_department=\(departmentid)")
                            Alamofire.request(url,method: .post).responseJSON { response in

                                var data3 = response.result.value

                                if data3 != nil {
                                    var json3 = JSON(data3!)
                                    var statusList:[[String:String]] = []
                                    var count3: Int? = json3.array?.count
                                    for index3 in 0 ..< count3!{
                                        var statusid = json3[index3]["status_id"]
                                        var statusname = json3[index3]["status_name"]
                                        cell.status.text = "- "+"\(statusname)";
                                        var url:String = asyncObj.getUrl("ticket", operation: "get_tickets", filter: "vis_filter=status_id=\(statusid)&\(VIS_PREFIX)ticket.department_id=\(departmentid)")
                                        Alamofire.request(url,method: .post).responseJSON { response in

                                            var data4 = response.result.value

                                            var tcount: Int?
                                            var ticketcount:Int = 0
                                            if data4 != nil {
                                                var json4 = JSON(data4!)
                                                tcount = json4.array?.count
                                                for index3 in 0 ..< tcount! {
                                                    ticketcount = ticketcount + 1
                                                }
                                            }


                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }




                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }



    /*let hotelName = hotelNames[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = hotelName
    cell.addressLabel.text = hotels[hotelName]
    */
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. There's a lot of typos ("alomafier") and it's not clear at all what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: you are using a wrong approach for calling API. You just need to create a network class with alamofire request function and when you call this method just pass the completion handler into it and get all the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but it sounds like you expect the global variable to be updated immediately. In reality, it only gets updated once the response comes in.

Here's an example:

```
var status = "Nothing much"

Alamofire.request("https://example.org/something").responseJSON { response in
    // This code runs in the future, probably after a few seconds
    status = "Got a response!" 
}

// This code runs immediately
print(status) // Prints "Nothing much"
```

Here, the status (like your global variable) is initialized to a value. Next, an Alamofire request is sent, with a response callback that eventually updates the status variable. However, the program doesn't wait for the response to come in before continuing. That's why the next line prints out "Nothing much".

Comment: output is Nothing much .Then what should i have to do.

Comment: You should learn about asynchronous programming. It's a very important concept if you're using Alamofire. You could start at https://www.raywenderlich.com/121540/alamofire-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Sir i tried tableView.reloaddata()  ,its worked but problem is that it shows response infinity loop